# Use case expression for conditions that aren't grouped

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case, deviceid

I am using a case expression in a query to output device descriptions in a custom column if the USB device id is matched.  There will be multiple of the same base deviceid per machine due their usually being multiple devices from the manufacturer sharing a USB dongle or something.

The issue I am running into is two device manufacturers have the same base device ids. I can't know exactly every full device id and which manufacturer it belongs to, all I can do is go off the first parts. One of the manufacturers will list their name in a column for the unifying receiver, but not for the mouse and or keyboard or whatever else there may be that shows for the computer.

This all comes from wmi under win32_usbDevice.  So right now I have a case exppression where if deviceid like '%XXXXX%' and manufacturer like '%Logitech%' then 'Logitech Unifying Dongle'. But as I said for the mouse and keyboard or whatever else may be attached that has the same base device id the manufuctuerer will just be generic "standard system device" or "standard usb host controller"  etc.  For these I cannot know if belongs to device manufacturer 1 or if it belongs to the other.  I can assume that if of one of the devices matching that based id has logitech as manufacturer then the rest that show for that computer are logitech input devices.  I would like to include this logic in the case expression but this is what I do not know how to do without grouping the results based on computer name or declaring a variable for the computer name or something.

Here is an example of the results I get for one machine.

[image]

So is there any way I can use case or if for this?  Like if deviceid like '%046D&PID_C525B%' and [USB Device Name] not like '%Logitech%' but machine name is the same as same row returned with Logitech then 'Logitech Devices'
end as device description.

Comment: First thing, show us the query you are using to give us something to start from. Secondly please post data as formatted text not images.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a composite USB device where you have a parent device (the bottom entry in your picture) and several child nodes.

I'm not really sure what you would want to do with the information, but if you only want to separate the child nodes from the parent node it would probably be sufficient to filter on the following:

- deviceid like %046D&PID_C525B&% (this would result in the child nodes)
- deviceid like %046D&PID_C525B\% (this would result in the parent device)

Also, if you want to uniquely identify the manufacturer, you can also only use the Vendor ID (046D) which in this case corresponds with Logitech.
https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/046D

Comment: yes but that vendor id also corresponds with dell. Which is why i am trying to find a way to differentiate.  The deviceID with MI_00 will say logitech for manufacturer if its logitech.

Comment: Could you maybe post a sample of both situations so I may understand more clearly?